# Mouse Dragging problem

Tags: java

i'm having the problem of capturing all the coordinate value of pixels while dragging with the mouse using mousedragged event in java
while i'm dragging slowly i'm able to get all the coordinate value of pixels
but when i'm doing it fast i'm getting only one third of the pixel coordinate values
for example if i drag it slowly i'm getting 760 pixel values but when i'm doing it fast i'm getting only 60 pixel coordinate values
please help me

I need all the points because i'm going to use all those points for the signature comparision...
Project Description :
User will put the sign using mouse in log in page, this sign will be compared with the sign which the user already put in sign up page...

I'm going to compare the sign using the pixel values, so by getting all the coordinate values only i can compare the sign...
pls help me...

Comment: You say `mousedragged event in Java` yet you tagged `C#`?

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `C#` when you mention Java in your question?

Comment: i wouldn't login to a website which asks me to use "Mouse" to login.. i am not good at drawing with pencil even, hell with  mouse. Reconsider your Design.. customer won't like this.

Comment: "User will put the sign using mouse in log in page, ..".  Who can create a reasonable representation of their signature, using a mouse?  This idea sounds broken before it has started.

Answer (score 4):

Windows is not going to give you this, its up to the refresh rate of the Mouse, its DPI and the rate at which windows polls for the Mouse event. You are not going to get all pixels so you will need to make room for some ambiguity.

*(It doesn't matter which language you use Java or C#)*

Answer (score 2):

Mouse movement events occur every few milliseconds, not for every pixel movement, so when the mouse is moving rapidly, some pixels will be missed out. If you want every single pixel, you'll have to interpolate between pixels if the new location is not adjacent to the previous one. One way to interpolate the pixels between two coordinates is Bresenham's line algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenhams_line_algorithm

Edit: Fixed link.